# Duda en query sobre SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando introducir en una tabla_A las fechas distintas de la tabla_B. Estoy usando la siguiente consulta.

```
MERGE tabla_A AS A
USING ( SELECT   distinct CONVERT(DATE,DateTime) DateTime
FROM    table_B
WHERE  DateTime between DATEADD(mm, -18, GETDATE())  and getdate() 
)AS SOURCE
ON A.[Date]=SOURce.[Datetime]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT(
       [Date]
) 
VALUES(
         
       SOURCE.[DateTime]  
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE;
```

El problema esta que el formato de la columna de DateTime de la tabla_B esta en fecha y hora y en la tabla_A esta solo en fecha ya que es lo que queremos queremos solo las distintas fechas entre los 18 meses anteriores a la fecha actual de la tabla_A. Creo que mi error esta en esta parte del codigo:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT(
       [Date]
) 
VALUES(
         
       SOURCE.[DateTime]  
)
```

Que no deberia poner `SOURCE.[DateTime]`, ya que esto me esta introduciendo todas las fechas en ese periodo de tiempo y no las distintas. Alguna sugerencia?

[image: Estos serian los valores de la tabla inicial]

[image: Y esto es lo que quiero conseguir en la nueva tabla]

Siendo la imagen de arriba los valores de la tabla inicial y la imagen de abajo los valores que quiero en la tabla final.

Comment: La explicación es confusa. Sugiero poner un ejemplo con unos cuantos datos de entrada, y lo que quieres que suceda exactamente con dichos datos.

Answer (score 0):

Claramente el error está en la línea

```
USING ( SELECT distinct CONVERT(DATE,DateTime) DateTime
```

El `distinct` no puede ser de un `DateTime`, si lo que quieres son fechas únicas. Debes adaptar el `Convert` para que solo tome la fecha y no la fecha y hora, por ejemplo pasándolo a `Date` con un `Cast`.

```
USING ( SELECT distinct CAST(DateTime as Date) DateTime
```

O bien a un `varchar` mediante un `convert`

```
USING ( SELECT distinct convert(varchar, DateTime, 112) DateTime
```